# Detect if Chrome restores the page from yesterday

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a form with an date input field. If you load the page the input is filled with the current date. But if Chrome starts and restores the last opened tabs from yesterday, there is always the date from yesterday in the form. 
If I reload the page it shows the correct date. But I would like Chrome to show the current date right away.

Any clever idea how to fix this?

**Update**: Page is set to `cache-control:no-cache, private`.

Comment: Perhaps setting a timeout to refresh the date input solves your problem. I'm not sure if Chrome keeps event listeners alive after a page restore.

Comment: Isn't onDomReady triggered? Maybe you can debug this by also showing the time ... to not have to always wait a single day.

Comment: Is  the field populated by the server or by javascript?

Comment: @Alex: The field is populated by the server. I added a hidden date to the page. Looks like the page is restored completely from cache. I have to check form DOM events... Maybe there is something useful triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I placed a date field and a JavaScript on the page. Turns out the page is loaded from cache. There is still the date from yesterday in the form and the JavaScript is executed same way as on page load. If I compare the date I can detect the old page:

```
<input id="form_date" name="form_date" type="hidden" value="2017-12-19 17:52:08">
<script>
    // Day compare
    Date.prototype.sameDay = function(d) {
        return this.getFullYear() === d.getFullYear()
            && this.getDate() === d.getDate()
            && this.getMonth() === d.getMonth();
    };
    var x_today = new Date();
    var x_page_date = new Date($('#form_date').val());
    if (console && !x_today.sameDay( x_page_date )){
        console.log("Old page!");
        console.log('page date: ', x_page_date);
        console.log('today: ', x_today);
    }
</script>
```

From here you could reload the page or ask the user what to do.

Answer (score -2):

You can either use ajax or get the server date.

Comment: This is not really an answer, Do not comment in the answer section